# Hostgator nightmare with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I'm having an absolute nightmare with a clients site and Hostgator. Akeeba backup will not run as well as sporadic the server did not send any data -
 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (chrome, firefox, safari) and after discussing with the Akeeba support team the have indicated the problem seems to be with the PHP configuration on the server. Below is the response:

> it seems there's something getting in the way while we're trying to test the maximum execution time.
>   I just connected to your site and ran some tests.
>   I think there's something going on with your server: even if I simply try to save Joomla Global Configuration I get the "Didn't send any respond" page. This shouldn't happen on Joomla core pages, I think you should get in touch with your host and ask him to review your site.

I too have verified this by manually transferring the entire site to my own server environment and the problems do not appear.

The problem now is trying to get hostgator to understand, they are infuriating and do not seem to read the supplied information. Can anyone provide any advise on how I can explain to them what the issue is so I can try and get this resolved? I have wasted at least 3 hours on them with this and I am no closer at solving it.

Regards
Donna

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Settings**

If you suspect a PHP setting issue, there are a few settings you can check yourself without waiting on your support request to be escalated to someone who knows what they are doing.

Assuming the hosting account is using a recent version of cPanel (for example), you can check the PHP Settings in "Select PHP Version" or similar.

Check which extensions are enabled and compare this to a different hosting account with a similar website that works well (if you have access to one). Also compare the PHP Options.

If there are no obvious issues, try temporarily changing PHP to a different version. For example, if PHP is set to 7.0, change it to 5.6 or vice versa.

**.htaccess**

Try temporarily replacing the current .htaccess file with the contents of the supplied Joomla htaccess.txt file to see if this is causing the issue.

**Hosting Move**

If no solution can easily be found, consider moving to anther hosting company. This may be the most efficient solution as you have already proved the website works fine elsewhere.

A simple website can be moved in less than an hour using Akeeba Backup or similar and you have already spent about three hours with no solution yet.